# Ghost Blog: Dynamic Routing with static home page not working as expected

Tags: handlebars.js, self-hosting, ghost-blog

I have just set up a Ghost Blog. This is a [clean install on a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/one-clicks/ghost/), and it is up and running correctly.

By default, Ghost shows a list of *posts* when opened in the browser. I would like to have a *home page* at the `/` location, and have my posts available at `/blog`. From what I can tell, this can be achieved by using [Dynamic Routing](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/routing).

To simplify this, I thought I would be able to `page` (Ghost has the concept of [*pages*](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/pages/) and [posts](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/posts/)) as the *home page*. I could then render this page using the already existing `page.hbs` template.

Here is my `routes.yaml` file:

```
routes:
  /: 
    data: page.home
    template:
      - page

collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template:
      - index

taxonomies:
  tag: /blog/tag/{slug}/
  author: /blog/author/{slug}/
```

I have a page called *home*, but when I load the home page, I get an empty-ish page: just the footer displays.

There are no hints in the log that tells me what could be happening. Am I understanding [routes.yaml](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/routing) correct? Is `page.home` not how to pass data to a page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question on [forum.ghost.org](https://forum.ghost.org/t/dynamic-routing-with-static-home-page-not-working-as-expected) and got the answer I was looking for.

The solution is to use the [long-form](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/routing/#data) data notation as below. My `routes.yaml` file now looks like:

```
routes:
  /: 
    data: 
      post: page.home
    template: page

collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template:
      - index

taxonomies:
  tag: /blog/tag/{slug}/
  author: /blog/author/{slug}/
```

Now, when I load [example.com](http://#) the `page` *home* is loaded, and when I navigate to [example.com/blog](http://#) the *blog* is loaded